# How to filter input data based on selected value from dropdown menu?

Tags: reactjs

I want to filter array items in a textbox by selecting an item from dropdown...

```
selectValue = (event) =>{

    this.setState({select : event.target.value})
    console.log(this.state.select)
    let filteredContact

            if(this.state.topic == 'ShortName'){
        filteredContact = this.state.list.filter(
            (item) =>{
                return item.alpha3Code.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    })}
    else if(this.state.select === 'Capital'){
        filteredContact = this.state.list.filter(
            (item) =>{
                return item.capital.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    })}
    else if(this.state.select === 'Name'){
        // console.log('hello')
        filteredContact = this.state.list.filter(
            (item) =>{
                return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    })} 
}



       <select className="text" onChange={this.selectValue} >

                    <option>---Select Option---</option>
                    {this.state.topic.map(list => <option>{list}</option>)}
                </select>

  <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.valueChange}>/input>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see is you're setting the state `this.setState({select : event.target.value})` and immediately called the state `if(this.state.select)`.

This might not work as expected since react [setState behaves asynchronously](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3). So instead of checking with `this.state.select`, use `event.target.value` itself there also.

Secondly, the filter function is wrong. You don't have to do indexOf in filter.

Example:

```
else if(this.state.select === 'Capital'){
    filteredContact = this.state.list.filter((item) =>{
            return item.capital.toLowerCase() === this.state.search.toLowerCase() 
})}
```

Read on [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Small tip: while coding isolate individual pieces of code and check what is working and what is not so that you know what exactly is working. You can try on JSBin or similar resources, with a small [example](https://jsbin.com/somopeg/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: i tried to put what you said using this i also not able to search an array item by selection dropdown item

Comment: can you explain what the current behaviour is and what the expected behaviour is?

Comment: i expect when i change dropdown item to name then it will be trigger to textbox and i can search name by typing in textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the if statement in [`componentDidUpdate(prevState)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Then you do the if statement there

Or you can do `event.target.value` as suggested, you seem to not set `filteredContact` anywhere? Did you meant to put them on the state?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState){

  if(prevState.topic !== this.state.topic){
    if(this.state.topic == 'ShortName'){
    filteredContact = this.state.list.filter(
      (item) =>{
          return item.alpha3Code.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    })}
    else if(this.state.select === 'Capital'){
    filteredContact = this.state.list.filter(
      (item) =>{
          return item.capital.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    })}
    else if(this.state.select === 'Name'){
    // console.log('hello')
    filteredContact = this.state.list.filter(
      (item) =>{
          return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    })} 

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer....but what i want is that when i change the dropdown item to name that triggers to input then i can search the name through input box

Comment: Yeah, but the `filteredContact` variables is not assigned anywhere after you filter it? Maybe you want to setState to the filteredContact? Depends on where you put the data you still need to update it

Comment: i assigned filteredContact to map function which maps the data from api